# Can't find who handles the AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, spring, exception, handler

I wanted to secure my application by using jwt. I had no idea how to implement the logic so i got everything(well, only the security folder) from [this project on github](https://github.com/murraco/spring-boot-jwt/tree/master/src/main/java/murraco).

I also have a custom global error controller

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
```

The app seems to work fine but when i try to do a request at an endpoint with no token at all i don't get an exception, so my GlobalExceptionHandler is skipped and i get the default error response form like this

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-07-07T00:02:54.024+00:00",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "path": "/profile"
}
```

I really don't know who handles this error since i don't see anything in my terminal except from

```
 : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-07 03:25:11.071  INFO 19971 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-07 03:25:11.074  INFO 19971 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
```

I also tried [this method](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-access-denied-page) that some people suggest. Also just adding an Handler for the AccessDeniedException on the GlobalExceptionHandler didn't work. I guess that i should see something about AccessDeniedException not being handled in my terminal anyway.
The fact that i dont see it makes me think that something handles it but i dont want to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To find out how an `AccessDeniedException` exception is handled, use a **debugger**.

Create a handler method and make it throw the exception. Put a breakpoint on the `throw` statement. Now step through the code, back up the call stack, until you get to the code handling the exception, and "Viola!", you have your answer.

It is normally handled by method `handleSpringSecurityException(...)` in class [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.9.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html).

If the user is not logged in (anonymous) or was logged in with remember-me, then the login process is started.

Otherwise an `AccessDeniedHandler` is invoked. The default handler will respond with a 403 Forbidden, showing an error page.

Anyway, do the *debugging* yourself in your code, to learn exactly how the exception is handled in your setup.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't so clear. Not only i don't know how the exception is handled but also i don't know who throws it.
You say to create a handler method and throw the exception there but i don't understand what you mean. Where should i put this handler, in which class?
In any case, i think the answer lies on the security folder but i really don't know what's happening in the background.

Comment: @stathis94 Look at the source code for `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, and you'll see the `try-catch` block catching the exception. Then put a breakpoint in the beginning of the `handleSpringSecurityException()` method, then you can check the stacktrace of the exception to see where it was thrown.

Comment: There are only two try catch blocks. The first one is inside JwtTokenProvider.java and the second one inside JwtTokenFilter.java. Trying to do a get request without providing any token, i see that no exception is thrown inside these try blocks (i just println a message inside catch blocks but nothing gets printed).
I also see that the program gets to execute `filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);` inside the overriden `doFilterInternal`. But i don't understand what happends next.